# Docx.dll SaveAs method throws exception

Tags: docx

we have used [codeplex](http://docx.codeplex.com/) for saving docx on a network path.

But intermittently  the SaveAs(string path) function of this dll fails.

the path provided to the function is as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to create and download docx document:

```
DocX g_document;
g_document = WhitePageReport(dt, dtSub);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
g_document.SaveAs(ms);
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"WhitePageReport.doc\"");
Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
Response.End();
```